# asp:SqlDataSource - Debugging a parameterized query

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to see what the SQL looks like after the parameters are resolved?

For example here is a small part of my SQL:

`([Event].[Start_Time] LIKE @StartTimeValue)`

And my parm:

`SqlDataSourceObject.SelectParameters.Add("StartTimeValue", TypeCode.DateTime, StartTimeValue)`

But what does the final SQL look like when the parm @StartTimeValue is replaced with the value in StartTimeValue?

How can I see that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the database server?  From there you could run a tool like SQL Profiler.

Another way is to set a break point just before the query is executed and examine the variables that went in.  Usually the issue lies somewhere with the variables you're passing in (they are null, etc) and not with the resolved query itself.  You could also set it up in a SQL query window like so:

```
-- Declare the variable to be used.
DECLARE @StartTimeValue datetime;

-- Initialize the variable.
SET @StartTimeValue = '<PASTE VARIABLE VALUE YOU GOT FROM DEBUGGING HERE>';

SELECT * FROM [Event] WHERE ([Event].[Start_Time] LIKE @StartTimeValue);
```

Comment: Hi Mikey thanks for your input.  I did as you suggested and found my problem.

In SQL Server I created the query you suggested.  It failed the same way as my app (yea).  I changed the datatype of the declare to Time(7) what was used in the table and it worked.  So this took me back to my app and my parm.

SqlDataSourceObject.SelectParameters.Add("StartTimeValue", TypeCode.DateTime, StartTimeValue)

I changed "TypeCode.DateTime" to "System.Data.DbType.Time" and it worked !!!!!

THANKS !!!!

Comment: I sure would like to know if there's an answer to this question.  I've used the above method plenty of times, and usually that solves the problem, but I'm getting an invalid parameter error when running this using MS Access.  Other queries worked, I've looked at it from every angle.  I can see the values in debug. Did as suggested above cutting, pasting,  double-checked everything (query works fine).  No dice.  I'm going to remove the parameters and just paste the data in.  If it works, I'm leaving it, since there is really no chance for sql injection, but I would love to know...

Comment: Steve, do you think it could have been a mismatch between the data types on the .net side vs. the access side?